# wget download and rename files that originally have no file extension

Tags: wget

Have a wget download I'm trying to perform.

It downloads several thousand files, unless I start to restrict the file type (junk files etc).  In theory restricting the file type is fine.

However there are lots of files that wget downloads without a file extension, that when manually opened with Adobe for example, are actually PDF's.  These are actually the files I want.

Restricting the wget to filetype PDF does not download these files.

So far my syntax is **wget -r --no-parent A.pdf www.websitehere.com**

Using **wget -r --no-parent www.websitehere.com** brings me every file type, so in theory I have everything.  But this means I have 1000's of junk files to remove, and then several hundred of the useful files of unknown file type to rename.

Any ideas on how to wget and save the files with the appropriate file extension?

Alternatively, a way restrict the wget to only files *without* a file extension, and then a separate batch method to determine the file type and rename appropriately?

Manually testing every file to determine the appropriate application will take a lot of time.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: You only have to read 4 bytes from each file and check for "%PDF" which should be hardly noticeable compared to the time for wget to download the file and put it on disk. You could do this work in a separate thread even.

Comment: Great thanks for the input - would certainly be quicker than re-downloading.  I suspect you refer to some methodology like the one seen here? http://superuser.com/questions/186942/renaming-multiple-file-extensions-based-on-a-condition

Comment: Ended up not changing the wget solution; just doing the bulk download of everything, and then processed file change after.  Solution to bulk renaming of unknown file types here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822865/method-to-inspect-first-4-bytes-and-rename-file-extension

Answer (score 13):

`wget` has an `--adjust-extension` option, which will add the correct extensions to HTML and CSS files. Other files (like PDFs) may not work, though. [See the complete documentation here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#HTTP-Options).